# How to exit script if file doesn't exist

Tags: vbscript, file-exists

I had this script working perfectly, but then I realized that if a file doesn't exist, it errors.  I have tried to figure out a way to accommodate for this, but I keep getting various error messages.

The following is my most recent attempt.

```
Dim fso, folder, file, todaysDate, recentFile, folder1, folder2, folderName1, folderName2 
Dim folderName, searchFileName, renameFileTo

folderName1 = "C:\Lif\TMI\"
folderName2 = "C:\Lif\TMA\"
todaysDate  = Date()

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder1 = fso.GetFolder(folderName1)
Set folder2 = fso.GetFolder(folderName2)  
Set recentFile = Nothing

For Each file In folder1.Files  
    If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate Then
        Set recentFile = file
    End If
    Exit For
Next

If fso.FileExists(recentfile) Then 
    recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
End If

For Each file In folder2.Files    
    If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate Then
        Set recentFile = file
    End If
    Exit For
Next

If fso.FileExists(recentfile) Then 
    recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "_", "A_")
End If
```

I have also tried this:

```
For Each file In folder1.Files    
    If fso.FileExists(file) Then
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate Then
        Set recentFile = file
        Exit For
    End IF
Next

recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
```

---

I have tried to implement the script that @Answar suggested, but I can't figure out how to get both name changes to work with this.

I apologize for the length, but I wanted to show everything I have tried.

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file
 End IF
 Exit For

 Next

 recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")

 If Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
  WScript.Quit 0
 End If
```

and

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file

 ElseIf Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
    WScript.Quit 0
 End If
 Exit For

 Next

 recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
```

and

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file
 End IF
 Exit For

 Next

 If recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 ElseIf Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
     WScript.Quit 0
 End If
```

and

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file
 End IF
 Exit For

 Next

 For each recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt") Then
 If fso.FileExists(recentFile) 
     WScript.Quit 0
 End If
 Exit For
```

and

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file
        recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 ElseIf fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
 End IF
 Exit For

 Next
```

and

```
 For each file In folder1.Files  
     If (recentFile is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate then
    Set recentFile = file
 End IF
 Exit For

 Next

 If recentFile.Name Then
     Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 ElseIf Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
     WScript.Quit 0
 End If
```

and

```
 For Each file In folder1.Files  
    If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
 ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate Then
        Set recentFile = file
    End If
    Exit For
 Next

 If fso.FileExists(recentfile) Then 
    recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 End If

 For Each file In folder2.Files    
    If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then 
        Set recentFile = file
    ElseIf DateValue (file.DateLastModified) = todaysDate Then
        Set recentFile = file
    End If
    Exit For
 Next

 If fso.FileExists(recentfile) Then 
    recentFile.Name = Replace(recentFile.Name, "_", "A_")
 If Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
    WScript.Quit 0
 End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exit if the file doesn't exist:

```
If Not fso.FileExists(recentFile) Then
  WScript.Quit 0
End If
```

Change 0 to a value >0 if you want the exit code to indicates an error.

Comment: I have tried to add this statement in a variety of different ways, but I cannot get the entire script to work with this added in.  

The script renames two different files in two different locations and I have been successful at getting it to work during the first name change, but not the second.

I pressed enter too soon - I will update with some of my attempts in my main post.

Comment: Please describe in detail what you want to achieve and what doesn't work as expected. Include all errors you're getting. Trying to shotgun the problem by putting my code snippet in random places is unlikely to help if you don't know what you're doing.